# Promt location on Fb message by Bot framework (nodejs v4)

Tags: node.js, botframework

```
const quickReply = {
    channelData: {
        "message": {
            "text": "Where are you?",
            "quick_replies": [
                {
                    "content_type":"location"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


return await stepContext.prompt(LOCATION, { prompt: quickReply }, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
```

I read syntax to prompt location is { "content_type":"location"} but fb message don't show button share location and i have error, please help me.

Comment: You question is unclear, can you be more specific on what is your problem, what do you try to accomplish and the error you receive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Messenger removed support for location quick replies last October, which is why the button isn’t rendering in the chat window. Take a look at Facebook’s developer document on quick replies for more details.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies/#locations

Comment: how can i get user's location, please help me?

Comment: I would recommend using a text prompt and LUIS’s prebuilt [geographyV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-geographyv2?tabs=V3) prebuilt entity to ask the user for their location.